# Collapsing and opening a div via a close button

Tags: javascript, html, expandable

I am trying to build using javascript a panel that expands out of the right side of the browser window, in which it will hold information. I have managed to get the div to expand on click but I need it to expand on hover, and also close with an x in the corner to return to its original state.

http://jsfiddle.net/8zGp9/

I hope this is clear, my Fiddle is above.

```
<div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hover`. The first function will take action on hover and the second when you hover out. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8zGp9/5/)

```
$("#slidingpanel").hover(function(e){
    $(this).animate({
        width: 200
    },100);
},function(e){
    $(this).animate({
        width: 30
    },100);
});
```

If you want to close your div on click only you can try this:

```
$("#slidingpanel").hover(function(e){
    $(this).animate({
        width: 200
    },100);
    $("#closeButton").css("display", "inline-block");    
});

$("#closeButton").click(function(){
    $("#slidingpanel").animate({
        width: 30
    },100);
    $(this).css("display", "none").delay(200);
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8zGp9/7/)

I located the X outside because if it's inside once you clicked it and moved the mouse, the hover will be fired again.

Comment: PERFECT! THANKS AND WELL DONE

Answer (score 0):

use hover function of jQuery. the code is just a example, you need to fix the x positione and deal with the div width : http://jsfiddle.net/8zGp9/4/

html:

```
<div id="slidingpanel">  
        <div id="closepanle">x</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#slidingpanel {
position: fixed;
width: 30px;
height: 200px;
z-index: 1;
right: 0px;
border:1px solid black;
}
#closepanle{
   position: inherit; 
   cursor:pointer;
   top:1;
}
```

js:

```
$("#slidingpanel").hover(function(){
  expandDiv(this);
 });
$("#closepanle").click(function(){
    closeDiv("#slidingpanel");
});

 function expandDiv(selector){    
    $(selector).animate({
        width: 200
    },100);
 }

 function closeDiv(selector){    
    $(selector).animate({
        width: 30
    },100);
 }
```

Comment: hello, in the fiddle it seems very erratic and seems to open and close at will. opening is fine by adjusting the expand area to 10px but the div does not close properly

Comment: other than that its perfect